# Placing an element at a given `row` and `col` position

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to place an element at a given `row` and `col` position. I have:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> myBoard = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
```

and a method:

```
public void set(int row, int col, T x)
```

When I `set` method for `ArrayList` it gives me error. Could smb please tell me what I should do to fix it? Thanks in advance!

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> myBoard = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
public void set(int row, int col, T x){
      if(myBoard.get(row).get(col).equals(this.element)){
          myBoard.set(myBoard.get(row).get(col), x);
      }
  }
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to set the `col`th column of the `row`th row, you need to obtain the row you wish to modify and then set the element `x` in the `col`th column of that row:

```
myBoard.get(row).set(col, x);
```

This will only work if your board has at least `row+1` rows and the `row`th row has at least `col+1` elements.